# Trying to show an image in shadowbox when user select a image in my input type file

Tags: php, jquery, shadowbox

I have an input file to select images.

I also have a `<div>` where I have a link to open a [jQuery Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) with image that user uploads.

And now Im trying to find how I can show in my `<div>` viewimage when I click on my `<a href="">` not a pre-defined image but the image that user choose on select a file.

Do you know how I can do this?

```
<label>
    <span class="field">Image:</span>
    <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" />
    <div class="viewimage">
        <img src="tim.php?src=../img/1.jpg&h=42" />  
        <a href="../img/1.jpg" rel="shadowbox" >See image</a>
    </div>                              
</label>
```